# SSH.NET How do I run the program then disconnect from ssh, keeping the program still running?

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I have some opencv programs in some Linux computers. Now I want to make a c# program as the switch in a windows computer to open those opencv program.

I have a original code which can open the opencv program

```
public void TrySomeSSh()
        {
            ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo(ip, _port, _username, new AuthenticationMethod[]{
    new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(_username,_password)});
            SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(conInfo);
            sshClient.Connect();
            if (sshClient.IsConnected)
            {
                SshCommand output1;
                 output1 = sshClient.RunCommand("export DISPLAY=\"127.0.0.1:10.0\" ; /home/MyName/MyOpencvProgram ");
              Console.WriteLine(output1.CommandText);
              Console.WriteLine(output1.Execute());

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not connected");
            }
            sshClient.Disconnect();
            sshClient.Dispose();
        }
```

However, there are some problems:

1. the c# program would hang on because the opencv program is still running. I cannot do other jobs in my c# program.
2. after I disconnect, the opencv program in the remote computer would be killed at the same time.

Now I can write something like this:

```
public void TrySomeSSh()
        {
            ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo(ip, _port, _username, new AuthenticationMethod[]{
    new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(_username,_password)});
            SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(conInfo);
            sshClient.Connect();
            if (sshClient.IsConnected)
            {

                ShellStream shellStream = sshClient.CreateShellStream(string.Empty, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                shellStream.WriteLine("export DISPLAY=\"127.0.0.1:10.0\"");
                shellStream.WriteLine("/home/MyName/MyOpencvProgram &");
                shellStream.WriteLine("disown -a");

                string line;
                while ((line = shellStream.ReadLine(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))) != null)
                {
                    string s = shellStream.Read();
                    Console.Write(s);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not connected");

            }
            Console.WriteLine("end connect");
            sshClient.Disconnect();
            sshClient.Dispose();
        }
```

somehow it can work,

but

1. I cannot find any way to do this by SshCommand since ShellStream is not recommended.
2. the TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) is not really clear that 2 second is enough or not.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: "after I disconnect, the opencv program in the remote computer would be killed at the same time" - usually [nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup), but there's also [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen). If it needs X you can create a headless X terminal for it to connect to too.

Comment: "I cannot do other jobs in my c# program." - yes you can, e.g. by running this SSH connection on a background thread which is easiest nowadays with async/await (once you've understood how that all works)

Comment: Did you try adding `disown` to your command-line in `RunCommand`?

Comment: I have ever try something like

sshClient.RunCommand("export DISPLAY=\"127.0.0.1:10.0\" ; /home/MyName/MyOpencvProgram & ; disown -a");

all of three commands are executed but nothing happen. If there is no "&" in command it would run the opencv program but hang on (and output opencv log continuously ) .the disown -a command would not be executed.

Comment: You want to run the method as a background task so you code and run other methods in parallel.  Changing the shell command line options are not going to solve issue.  The ssClient is blocking and will not return until the task is completed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put all the process and its derived in a new thread. In this fashion the main Thread (UIG) remain free and running.